# Android - Missing binary protection - Realm

Tags: android, binary, realm, elf

I have an application with Realm. It is running successfully I have no issues with that. Now I have scan my application with https://www.ostorlab.co/

It throwing an error  **ELF binaries do not enforce secure binary properties**

Which states that **Missing binary protection**

Also they suggest an solution like the following:

**Rebuilding Realm library with -fstack-protector flag in GCC that you need to set in the file android.toolchain.cmake.**

I have no idea how to achieve this. If anyone knows the solution please give me a suggestion.

Comment: See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4553#issuecomment-297126814

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: You have to check out Realm-Core (and Realm-Java) repositories, add the flag, then compile it. You need a Linux or a Mac for that, or you can *somehow* use their Docker file otherwise https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/911#issuecomment-255310416

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4553#issuecomment-297126814, we consider this a false positive as this is not a valid attack vector when you go through the Java API's. If you somehow are in a position to call the C++ API's directly (which would be needed to exploit this), then you already have a level of access to the device where you can just download the Realm file or read/modify it directly.